# Как удалять id человека остановившего бота из txt?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В общем, хотел написать рассылку для тг-бота(питон, либа-телебот), т.е. когда пишу определённую команду и текст, то всем пользователем отправляется этот текст

Но есть такая проблема:

Если человек остановит бота, то появляется ошибка 403, как я понял, бот тупо не может отправить сообщение 1му человеку и из-за этого оно не отправляется всем
т.е. надо это скорей всего как-то с помощью try проверять(если не удалось отправить, то нужно удалить этот id из txt)

Вот код:

````
def start(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedusers:
        joinedfile = open('D:/Учёба/Колледж/проект/SUAImagazine_bot/joined.txt', 'a')
        joinedfile.write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
        joinedusers.add(message.chat.id)
#Рассылка
joinedfile = open('D:/Учёба/Колледж/проект/SUAImagazine_bot/joined.txt', 'r')
joinedusers = set()
for line in joinedfile:
    joinedusers.add(line.strip())
joinedfile.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['adminpanel'])
def mess(message):
    for user in joinedusers:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])```
````

Comment: Во-первых, нужно хранить информацию в базе данных. Во-вторых, можно отлавливать ошибку с помощью `try except`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def start(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedusers:
        with open('D:/Учёба/Колледж/проект/SUAImagazine_bot/joined.txt', 'a') as joinedfile:
            joinedfile.write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
            joinedusers.add(message.chat.id)
#Рассылка
joinedfile = open('D:/Учёба/Колледж/проект/SUAImagazine_bot/joined.txt', 'r')
joinedusers = set()
for line in joinedfile:
    joinedusers.add(line.strip())
joinedfile.close()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['adminpanel'])
def mess(message):
    for user in joinedusers:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])


@bot.my_chat_member_handler(None)
def ban_handler(member: telebot.types.ChatMemberUpdated):
    if member.new_chat_member.status in ["restricted", "kicked", "left"]:
        # код здесь сработает, если пользователь остановит бота
        joinedusers.remove(str(member.chat.id))
    else:
        # код здесь сработает, если пользователь уберёт бота из чс в настройках (ошибки 403 не будет)
        joinedusers.add(str(member.chat.id))
    # нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО сохранить файл
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).